# open with default editor and wait to be closed

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

we're developing an app that should be able to open specified file with default editor application. (so if it is .doc - it suppose to be opened by MSWord or openOffice)

But I also need to wait until user will close the editor, check if it was changed (by size and date), and upload it to the server.

So the following steps:
1) find def editor
2) open file
3) wait it be closed
4) do smth after that with the file.

now results of my research:
-> opening by def editor is simple:
  file.openWithDefaultApplication();
but there is no way to know that editor is closed (maybe by checking that file is not locked in timer???)

-> i can start the native process and pass file as parameter BUT looks like the code 
 NativeApplication.nativeApplication.getDefaultApplication(file.extension);
does not work for any extension :( - it doesnt work for "rtf", "doc" but works for "pdf"... and [file.openWithDefaultApplication()] works fine with any file!

any suggestions? 
thx in advance!

Comment: did you manage to do it? I'm in a very similar situation right now :(

Comment: we decided to do it this way: store the date and size of the file, if it is changed - we're uploading the file to the server. if not - keep listening. if no changes during expiration period - file is removed. The reason is that openOffice is not locking the file so there is no easy way to find out is it opened/closed or not.

Answer (score 3):

> but there is no way to know that
>   editor is closed

Correct.  I do not believe what you want to do is possible with AIR.  How would AIR be able to tell whether the file is open or not?  You might want to look into using [NativeProcess](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html); but that would be reliant on the underlying OS/default program exposing APIs to let you know when the program was open and/or closed.

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion is that you don't have the Air application watch the file, but instead show a popup that say 'click okay when done editing file' and then upload it based on that.

The only other way I can think of this working is if you create both a .bat and a .sh file 
(for both windows and macs/linux; select one or the other depending on the os) which open the file you want through NativeProcess (and of course, put 'wait') and then listen for the close event.